# SSIS set priorities from many tasks to one

Tags: ssis, operator-precedence, dataflowtask

This is the scenario:
[image: ssis scenario]

The first task check the presence of some files, write variables and with expressions check which data flow task run. And here everything works.

I would like to have the last task turned on when all of the previous tasks have been completed. Some tasks may not be executed. Maybe only four of them have been processed. Boolean variables in the expressions determine its execution.

I tried to set the constraint as "Expression or costraint" and check if the result is positive and all constraints are grouped by logic OR.
However, when one of the tasks is over, the last task is started. Instead, I should wait for all the tasks to finish before starting the last one.

If a different costraints grouping is set (logic AND), the last task does not run because some data flow task aren't executed.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: use a Boolean variable say IsGoodToGo, set it TRUE by default. If any of the above mention task fails set it to false using expressionTask and before the last task check if it is TRUE then continue execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only run the last step after all of the middle tasks have completed, put the first task and all the middle tasks in a single Sequence Container.   Then just draw a precedence constraint from the container to the last task.